Clear Pivot Table in Excel 2013: Method 'ClearTable' of object 'PivotTable' failed
I have a macro which creates pivot tables.
It clears the current pivot table using myPivot.ClearTable then creates the new pivot table.
This works on several PCs, but not on a colleague's Excel 2013.

Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
Method 'ClearTable' of object 'PivotTable' failed

Sub setpivotSPREADALL()

Dim myPivot As Variant

Set myPivot = Worksheets("1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

Set PivotDate = Worksheets("1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum")

myPivot.ClearTable '' Line highlighted by debugmode

myPivot.PivotFields("Field1").Orientation = xlRowField '' Category Row
myPivot.PivotFields("Field1").Position = 1

myPivot.PivotFields("Field2").Orientation = xlRowField '' Object Row
myPivot.PivotFields("Field2").Position = 2

myPivot.PivotFields("Field3").Orientation = xlRowField '' Understring Row
myPivot.PivotFields("Field3").Position = 3

myPivot.PivotFields("Field4").Orientation = xlColumnField '' Date Column
myPivot.PivotFields("Field4").Position = 1

I have Microsoft Office LTSC Professional plus 2021 version.
I think there is something with versions compatibility and I have to use some different lines of code.
